# Preventing multiple insertions of a connection between two users (SQL / SQLite)

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, sql-insert, unique-constraint

I am currently working on a project where I want to store a connection between two users and some additional information in a SQLite database. The problem is that I want to store this connection exactly once and not have multiple entries for this connection.

So if I have userA and userB and for example the time this connection was made (userA, userB, time), I don't want to be able to store the reverse (userB, userA, time) as well.

My current solution is to sort the users and combine them into a single string, which is then used to create a primary key (userAuserB, userA, userB, time), preventing re-insertion. But I don't think this is the right way to do it.

Is there a better solution for this task?

Thanks, Ypselon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your version of SQLite is 3.31.0+ you can define 2 [generated columns](https://www.sqlite.org/gencol.html) in the table which will be the min and the max connection values of the columns and then you can define a unique constraint for them:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
  userA TEXT,
  userB TEXT,
  user1 GENERATED AS (MIN(userA, userB)),
  user2 GENERATED AS (MAX(userA, userB)),
  UNIQUE(user1, user2)
);
```

The generated columns are *virtual*, meaning that they are not stored in the table.

See the [demo](https://sqliteonline.com/#share=d36b36f8287423e346c5616d59be0d35f180ac248972923669d24cd356577d0d).